Is it safe to use the same io_context for multiple threads to call methods in different intervals?
I have an application in which i need to call multiple methods inside a single method through different threads.
Each method is supposed to be called with different intervals.
I am using the boost library to implement the calling functions repeatedly with different intervals.
My question is that if it is safe to use a single boost::asio::io_context for all of them?
Here is a sample code that shows how the code will look like.
The enum types and class/ structure declaration will be
struct TestTimerContext {
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer;
    NssStatsTimerContext(boost::asio::io_context& io) : timer(io) {}
};


enum MethodTypes { FIRST = 0, SECOND = 1, THIRD = 2 };

class Myclass {
 
  public:
    Myclass(boost::asio::io_context& io): io_context_(io) {}
    void start_process (vector<bool> condistions, vector<uint32> intervals);

    std::thread                  method_1_thread_;
    std::thread                  method_2_thread_;
    std::thread                  method_3_thread_;
    
  private:
     boost::asio::io_context io_context_;
     
     void start_method_thread (uint32 interval, MethodTypes method_type);
 

     void func_cb ( const boost::system::error_code& err, uint32_t interval, MethodTypes method_type);

     void  method1 (uint32 interval);
     void  method1 (uint32 interval);
     void  method1 (uint32 interval);

};
And here will be how exactly i am using the boost::asio::io_context to call the method with different intervals. I just removed all the logic from my sample codes to share the high level idea and keep it simple
Myclass::start_process (vector<bool> condistions, vector<uint32> intervals) {
    if (conditions[0]) {
        method_1_thread_ = std::thread([&]() {
            start_method_thread (intervals[0], MethodTypes::FIRST);
        });
    }
    if (conditions[1]) {
        method_2_thread_ = std::thread([&]() {
             start_method_thread (intervals[1], MethodTypes::SECOND);
        });
        
    }
    if (conditions[2]) {
       method_3_thread_ = std::thread([&]() {
            start_method_thread (intervals[2], MethodTypes::THIRD);
        });
    }
    if (method_1_thread_.joinable()) {
        method_1_thread_.join();
    }
    if (method_2_thread_.joinable()) {
        method_2_thread_.join();
    }
    if (method_3_thread_.joinable()) {
        method_3_thread_.join();
    }
}


void Myclass:: start_method_thread (uint32 interval, MethodTypes method_type) {
    std::unique_ptr<TestTimerContext> ctx;
    ctx           = std::make_unique<TestTimerContext>(io_context_);
    auto& ctx_ref = *ctx;
    
    if (interval ==0) {
        func_cb( err, interval, method_type);
    } else {
        
        ctx_ref.timer.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        ctx_ref.timer.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code& err) mutable {
            func_cb( err, interval, method_type);
        });
    }
}



void Myclass::func_cb (
    const boost::system::error_code& err,
    uint32_t                         interval,
    MethodTypes                         method_type) {

    if (err) {
        cout<<"cb function has an error"<<endl;
        return;
    }

    switch (method_type) {
    case MethodTypes::FIRST:
        method1();
        break;
    case MethodTypes::SECOND:
        methdo2();
        break;
    case MethodTypes::THIRD:
        method3();
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"method type is not supported"<<end;
        return;
    }

    if (interval == 0) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        auto  ctx     = Arc<TestTimerContext>(io_context_);
        auto& ctx_ref = *ctx;

        ctx_ref.timer.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        ctx_ref.timer.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code& err) mutable {
            func_cb(err, interval, method_type);
        });
    }
}

void Myclass::method1 () {
    cout<<"method1 is called!"<<end;
    
}

void Myclass::method2 (){
    cout<<"method3 is called!"<<end;
}

void Myclass::method3 (){
    cout<<"method3 is called!"<<end;
}

I appreciate if you can share your feedbacks, but yeah my major question is if i can share the same io_context variable among all of these threads?

What benefit do you think you're getting from calling async_wait on different threads?  To be clear, the callback will not be called on the thread that called async_wait; it will be called on whatever thread or threads are calling io_context_.run.  async_wait returns immediately.

https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.28.0/doc/asio/reference/io_context.html#asio.reference.io_context.thread_safety
